# Link to different's route anchor in Angularjs app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

I've built a simple angular app.
I have a navigation menu like this:

**HOME - SHOW - EXTRAS - BLOG**

Home, show and extras, are suposed to be anchor links within / route while BLOG is another route or partial view of my angular app.
When the BLOG view is loaded, I click an item and load a dynamic POST.
I need to link HOME - SHOW and EXTRAS to the anchor in the HOME view.

I've read a lot of questions here but none helpful.

I've also tried using something like this:

```
<a href="#!/#extras" target="_self">EXTRAS</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/#extras">EXTRAS</a>
```

both, also with ng-href. I can accomplish the solution in any way.

**EDIT**
Also tried this but nothing happened:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

**/EDIT**

**EDIT2**
Here's my folder structure:

```
index.html
----pages
--------home.html
--------blog-list.html
--------blog-post.html
```

Basically its a one page web plus blog.

**/EDIT2**

This are my routes:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.routes')
    .config(routesConfig);

routesConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
function routesConfig($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html'
        ,controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/blog', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/blog-list.html'
        ,controller: 'timelineCtrl'
    })
    .when('/post/:article_id', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/blog-post.html'
        ,controller: 'timelineItemCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}
})();
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `.module('app.routes', ["ngRoute"]` you need to inject route dependency, it seems to be missing or unless the code where you inject dependencies are in a different file.

Comment: They are in the same file. Different module.